# In the photoelectric effect, is energy transferred to the electron if $hf < \phi$?

Tags: photoelectric-effect

My notes describe the photoelectric effect as an 'all or nothing' interaction, in which a photon either gives up all of its energy to the electron or gives up none of its energy.

Does this mean that if $hf < \phi$, the photon will transfer none of its energy to the electron? Or is energy still transferred to the electron, but no photoelectrons are emitted since the energy delivered is less than the work function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes energy can be transferred to electrons without the electron being ejected but it wouldn’t be called the photoelectric affect. Most of the time that is what happens. The energy is transferred to the electron which then rises to a higher energy level. Then a new photon is emitted. Everything you see around you is from that process.